# Limit of $x_n = \sqrt{2+x_{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to find quite a simple limit i.e.  for $x_n = \sqrt{2+x_{n-1}}$ and $x_1 = \sqrt{2}$, find:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_n}$$

So in order to use recurrence relations to find the limit, I must first prove that this limit exists. So i thought I would prove that this sequence is monotone sequence and bounded from above.

By solving $x_{n+1} > x_n$ I got that this holds for $-1 < x_n <2$ . So i thought immediately that by proving $x_n <2$ proves the existence of this limit.

This part seems to be causing me problems. Proving:

> $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}} <2$$

Now this is intuitive and very simple but I need a formal proof. I did this:
$$\sqrt{2} < 2 $$
Adding 2 to both sides gives:
$$2+\sqrt{2} < 4$$
Square rooting :
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} < 2$$
Repeating the process $n$ times:
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}...}} < 2$$

But i am not sure of this proof is formal enough or if it is a valid proof. I believe this problem has been solved before but i couldn't find it on math.stackexchange.com .

Of course, calculating the limit gives:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } {x_n} = 2$$

**Summary:** Is the proof provided above formal enough, and if there are other proofs, I would like to see them?

Comment: Hint: you can use induction.

Comment: You can use induction $x_n < 2 \implies x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+2}<2$ in much the same way...

Comment: You see this. I think you will get your answer.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418807/proving-convergence-of-a-series-and-then-finding-limit/1418830#1418830

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Yes, thank you. I know this is a common problem so i knew there already is a solution here , but i just couldn't find it :D

Comment: @Macavity Well, yes, I basically did use the induction there. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another proof:
$0<|x_n-2| = \dfrac{|x_{n-1}-2|}{\sqrt{x_{n-1}+2}+2}<\dfrac{|x_{n-1}-2|}{3}<\dfrac{|x_{n-2}-2|}{9}<\cdots <\dfrac{|x_1-2|}{3^{n-1}}<\dfrac{1}{3^{n-1}}$, and apply squeeze theorem, the limit is $2$ as claimed.